# how to create a trade capture report using Appia fix engine?

Tags: fix-protocol

I'm trying to write a simulator to create FIX message in java Using Appia.jar.

I am able to generate execution report by initializing ExecutionReport.class object..
But i am not able to find any class file specific to trade capture report..please help me out..

Comment: `Appia` is a propreitary library and it will be better to ask the library developers, as they should provide you with documents and help.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the protocol are you using? TradeCapture reports were only added in version 4.3 so if you are using a version previous to that (say 4.2 which is what we mostly use in my work) there will be no trade capture report object available.